# How to calculate run time memory in Matlab?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, matlab-deployment

Today i am developing one IEEE paper. In that paper mentioned about run time memory. How to calculate run time memory of a program in Matlab?

Answer (score 3):

```
profile on

SOME CODE

profile off

profile_info = profview   %HTML string of the memory profile
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me about running memory size while program running?

Comment: I'm getting this answer. memory--->Maximum possible array:            1108 MB (1.161e+009 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:   1429 MB (1.498e+009 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:              305 MB (3.202e+008 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):             1910 MB (2.003e+009 bytes)